# Cannot open Steam (weird error on terminal)

Tags: steam

I have reinstalled Steam but when I try to run it from terminal, it gives me this:

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/blade/.steam/steam to /home/blade/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on elementary 0.4 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
*** Error in `/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam': free(): invalid pointer: 0xffa59690 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xf737b377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xf73812f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dbb1)[0xf7381bb1]
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XFree+0x1b)[0xf76aef1b]
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x51406)[0x56629406]
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x520ee)[0x5662a0ee]
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x22420)[0x565fa420]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xf732c637]
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x25ae9)[0x565fdae9]
======= Memory map: ========
565d8000-56989000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4070159                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
56989000-5699d000 r--p 003b1000 08:04 4070159                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
5699d000-569aa000 rw-p 003c5000 08:04 4070159                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
569aa000-569ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
56ce2000-56e55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
f6000000-f6021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6021000-f6100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f61b6000-f61bd000 r--s 00000000 08:03 1584139                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
f61bd000-f61d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1188344                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
f61d6000-f61d7000 r--p 00018000 08:03 1188344                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
f61d7000-f61d8000 rw-p 00019000 08:03 1188344                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
f61d8000-f61e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584843                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
f61e2000-f61e3000 r--p 00009000 08:03 1584843                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
f61e3000-f61e4000 rw-p 0000a000 08:03 1584843                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
f61e4000-f61f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1188326                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
f61f8000-f61f9000 r--p 00013000 08:03 1188326                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
f61f9000-f61fa000 rw-p 00014000 08:03 1188326                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
f61fa000-f6206000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1570703                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
f6206000-f6207000 r--p 0000b000 08:03 1570703                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
f6207000-f6208000 rw-p 0000c000 08:03 1570703                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
f6208000-f6210000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1570699                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
f6210000-f6211000 r--p 00007000 08:03 1570699                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
f6211000-f6212000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 1570699                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
f6212000-f6235000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1570695                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
f6235000-f6236000 r--p 00022000 08:03 1570695                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
f6236000-f6237000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 1570695                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
f6237000-f62e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1188328                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
f62e2000-f62e3000 r--p 000aa000 08:03 1188328                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
f62e3000-f62e6000 rw-p 000ab000 08:03 1188328                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
f62e6000-f6a00000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1570716                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
f6a00000-f6a01000 ---p 0071a000 08:03 1570716                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
f6a01000-f6a2a000 r--p 0071a000 08:03 1570716                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
f6a2a000-f6a30000 rw-p 00743000 08:03 1570716                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
f6a30000-f6a36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6a36000-f6a55000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1188342                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
f6a55000-f6a56000 r--p 0001e000 08:03 1188342                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
f6a56000-f6a57000 rw-p 0001f000 08:03 1188342                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
f6a57000-f6a67000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1569819                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
f6a67000-f6a68000 r--p 0000f000 08:03 1569819                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
f6a68000-f6a69000 rw-p 00010000 08:03 1569819                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
f6a69000-f6a6e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584343                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6a6e000-f6a6f000 r--p 00004000 08:03 1584343                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6a6f000-f6a70000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 1584343                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
f6a70000-f6a74000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584831                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
f6a74000-f6a75000 r--p 00003000 08:03 1584831                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
f6a75000-f6a76000 rw-p 00004000 08:03 1584831                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
f6a76000-f6a8e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584835                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
f6a8e000-f6a8f000 ---p 00018000 08:03 1584835                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
f6a8f000-f6a90000 r--p 00018000 08:03 1584835                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
f6a90000-f6a91000 rw-p 00019000 08:03 1584835                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
f6a91000-f6a92000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584829                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
f6a92000-f6a93000 r--p 00000000 08:03 1584829                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
f6a93000-f6a94000 rw-p 00001000 08:03 1584829                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
f6a94000-f6a99000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584329                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6a99000-f6a9a000 r--p 00004000 08:03 1584329                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6a9a000-f6a9b000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 1584329                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f6a9b000-f6a9d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584335                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
f6a9d000-f6a9e000 r--p 00001000 08:03 1584335                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
f6a9e000-f6a9f000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 1584335                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
f6a9f000-f6ab2000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1570730                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
f6ab2000-f6ab3000 ---p 00013000 08:03 1570730                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
f6ab3000-f6ab5000 r--p 00013000 08:03 1570730                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
f6ab5000-f6abb000 rwxp 00015000 08:03 1570730                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
f6abb000-f6ae1000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1188340                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
f6ae1000-f6ae2000 ---p 00026000 08:03 1188340                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
f6ae2000-f6ae4000 r--p 00026000 08:03 1188340                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
f6ae4000-f6ae5000 rw-p 00028000 08:03 1188340                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
f6ae5000-f6b4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1709395                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
f6b4f000-f6b51000 r--p 00069000 08:03 1709395                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
f6b51000-f6b56000 rwxp 0006b000 08:03 1709395                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
f6b5c000-f6b7e000 r--p 00000000 08:03 144845                             /usr/share/locale-langpack/it/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
f6b7e000-f6bba000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4070155                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/crashhandler.so
f6bba000-f6bbb000 r--p 0003c000 08:04 4070155                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/crashhandler.so
f6bbb000-f6bbc000 rw-p 0003d000 08:04 4070155                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/crashhandler.so
f6bbc000-f6f95000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6f95000-f70c5000 r--p 004ab000 08:03 1441954                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
f70c5000-f72c5000 r--p 00000000 08:03 1441954                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
f72c5000-f72c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f72c8000-f72cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325603                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72cd000-f72ce000 r--p 00004000 08:04 4325603                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72ce000-f72cf000 rw-p 00005000 08:04 4325603                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72cf000-f72d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325699                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72d1000-f72d2000 r--p 00001000 08:04 4325699                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72d2000-f72d3000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 4325699                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72d3000-f72d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f72d4000-f72f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 790012                             /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f72f0000-f72f1000 r--p 0001b000 08:04 790012                             /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f72f1000-f72f2000 rw-p 0001c000 08:04 790012                             /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f72f2000-f7312000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325702                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f7312000-f7313000 r--p 0001f000 08:04 4325702                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f7313000-f7314000 rw-p 00020000 08:04 4325702                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f7314000-f74c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182654                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f74c3000-f74c4000 ---p 001af000 08:03 1182654                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f74c4000-f74c6000 r--p 001af000 08:03 1182654                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f74c6000-f74c7000 rw-p 001b1000 08:03 1182654                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f74c7000-f74ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f74ca000-f74e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182713                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
f74e3000-f74e4000 r--p 00018000 08:03 1182713                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
f74e4000-f74e5000 rw-p 00019000 08:03 1182713                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
f74e5000-f74e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f74e7000-f75e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325701                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
f75e2000-f75e6000 r--p 000fa000 08:04 4325701                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
f75e6000-f75e7000 rw-p 000fe000 08:04 4325701                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
f75e7000-f75ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f75ea000-f75ed000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182644                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
f75ed000-f75ee000 r--p 00002000 08:03 1182644                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
f75ee000-f75ef000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 1182644                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
f75ef000-f7642000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182711                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7642000-f7643000 r--p 00052000 08:03 1182711                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7643000-f7644000 rw-p 00053000 08:03 1182711                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7644000-f764b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182638                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
f764b000-f764c000 r--p 00006000 08:03 1182638                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
f764c000-f764d000 rw-p 00007000 08:03 1182638                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
f764d000-f764e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f764e000-f765e000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325595                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f765e000-f765f000 r--p 0000f000 08:04 4325595                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f765f000-f7660000 rw-p 00010000 08:04 4325595                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f7660000-f7661000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584341                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
f7661000-f7662000 r--p 00000000 08:03 1584341                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
f7662000-f7663000 rw-p 00001000 08:03 1584341                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
f7663000-f7668000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584839                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
f7668000-f7669000 ---p 00005000 08:03 1584839                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
f7669000-f766a000 r--p 00005000 08:03 1584839                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
f766a000-f766b000 rw-p 00006000 08:03 1584839                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
f766b000-f766d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584837                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
f766d000-f766e000 r--p 00001000 08:03 1584837                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
f766e000-f766f000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 1584837                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
f766f000-f7671000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1584833                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
f7671000-f7672000 r--p 00001000 08:03 1584833                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
f7672000-f7673000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 1584833                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
f7673000-f7674000 r--p 00718000 08:03 1441954                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
f7674000-f7675000 r--p 008a0000 08:03 1441954                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
f7675000-f77a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4325616                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f77a5000-f77a6000 r--p 00130000 08:04 4325616                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f77a6000-f77a8000 rw-p 00131000 08:04 4325616                            /home/blade/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f77a8000-f77ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77ab000-f77ad000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vvar]
f77ad000-f77ae000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f77ae000-f77d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 1182569                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f77d0000-f77d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77d1000-f77d2000 r--p 00022000 08:03 1182569                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f77d2000-f77d3000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 1182569                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
ffa3d000-ffa5f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2017-03-11 17:00:10] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
assert_20170311170010_1.dmp[13956]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20170311170010_1.dmp
assert_20170311170010_1.dmp[13956]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
assert_20170311170010_1.dmp[13956]: error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
assert_20170311170010_1.dmp[13956]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20170311170010_1.dmp'', upload no: ''libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory''
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: riga 713: 13953 Annullato               (core dump creato) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
/home/blade/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: riga 444: nessuna corrispondenza: ssfn*
```

I want to specify that I installed Steam before and worked perfectly but I uninstalled it because I didn't play too much.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try delete .steam in your home directory (It's hidden so you have to show hidden files). Then steam will start all over, hopefully it will fix your problem.

Comment: it still does not work: it asks me again to accept the term of service but doesn't open up

Comment: is it the same error popping up?

Comment: yep, the error seems to be tha same

Comment: okay try this: sudo apt install libcurl3:i386

Comment: ok now the error changed into this: http://pastebin.com/bhwSWuP8

Comment: Try delete the .steam directory again.

Comment: same error... I don't know why. Can be a problem of the desktop environment (I'm running XFCE right now)?

Comment: Lets try: sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi then reboot

Comment: It could be but it shouldn't.

Comment: I've already installed that package

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/618456760281557146/

Comment: any of the solutions listed works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar when I first installed steam. This is what worked for me.

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

rm $HOME/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

After this restart Steam and it should update and fix itself. At least in my case it did.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324659/how-to-install-steam-on-elementary-os-loki-64-bit